# CakePHP Sub Queries

Tags: cakephp

I want to show in the index view all users with a photo and the city.
Name and photo are ok.
The problem is the city.
I created model user:

```
public $hasOne = array(
        'Photo' => array(
            'className' => 'Photo',
            'dependent' => true
        ),
        'Scheda' => array(
            'className' => 'Scheda',
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
```

And the model City

```
class Citta extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = 'Citta';
}
```

and finally the UsersController

```
  public function index() {
          $data= $this->User->find('all', array(
                    'contain' => array('Photo'),
             'conditions'=>array('User.attivo' => '1'),
             'group'=>array('User.id'),
             'type'=>'INNER'));

$this->loadModel('Citta');      
$citta=$this->Citta->find('all', array(
 'conditions' => array('Scheda.citta_id = Citta.id'),
));
$this->set('user',$data);
$this->set('citta',$citta);        
  }
```

I received this error

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Citta'

SQL Query: SELECT `Citta`.`id`, `Citta`.`value` FROM `massaggi2`.`cittas` AS `Citta` LEFT JOIN `massaggi2`.`cittas` AS `Citta` ON (`Citta`.`citta_id` = `Citta`.`id`) WHERE `Scheda`.`citta_id` = `Citta`.`id`

What's wrong?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Citta hasOne Citta? is this an intended parent-child association?

Comment: I'm newbie in cakephp...probably I missed something.
How can modify Citta hasOne Citta?
I want to retrieve the city of each user

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that Citta hasOne Citta -- both named the same thing.  Just change up the name of the association that Citta has, for example:

```
class Citta extends AppModel {
     public $hasOne = array(
            'OtherCity' => array(
                 'className' => 'Citta',
                 'dependent' => false,
             );
      );
}
```